# R Script running via Windows Task Scheduler failing

Tags: r, automation, zip, scheduled-tasks

I have a couple of R scripts that I have scheduled to run via the `taskscheduleR` package. I keep getting errors on them when they run if they run.

The first uses the `zip` package to simply zip up a couple of directories (This one I even tried moving all the files to the C drive and it still fails with the same error):

```
# Lib Load ----
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(
    "zip"
    , "RDCOMClient"
)

# Zip Files ----
zipr(
    zipfile = "C:\\path_to_desktop\\Code.zip"
    , files = c(
        "S:\\path_to_files\\R"
        ,"S:\\path_to_files\\SQL"
        ,"S:\\path_to_files\\VB"
        )
    , include_directories = TRUE
    )
```

I get the following error only when run via the task scheduler (works fine when I hit run):

```
Loading required package: pacman
Error in zip_internal(zipfile, files, recurse, compression_level, append = FALSE,  : 
  Some files do not exist
Calls: zipr -> zip_internal
Execution halted
```

This one just does not even run but task scheduler says it completes - I get no long from taskscheduler so I know it does not run (Runs fine when I hit run in R-Studio):

```
# Lib Load ----
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")
pacman::p_load(
    "tidyverse"
    , "dbplyr"
    , "DBI"
    , "odbc"
    , "readxl"
)

# Load Excel File ----
df <- read_excel(
        path = "G:\\Desktop Working Files\\FridayFile.xlsx"
        , sheet = "Sheet1"
    )

# Make sure records are distinct
df <- df %>% 
    distinct()

# DB Connection ----
db_con <- dbConnect(
    odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server",
    Server = "server_name",
    Database = "db_name",
    Trusted_Connection = T
)

# Insert Records ----
dbWriteTable(
    db_con
    , Id(
        schema = "smsdss"
        , table = "c_friday_file"
    )
    , df
    , overwrite = TRUE
)

# DB Disconnect
dbDisconnect(db_con)

# Clean Env
rm(list = ls())
```

This one runs the database portion but does not write the file at the end (but it does when I hit run from R-Studio):

```
# Lib Load ----
if(!require(pacman)) install.packages("pacman")

pacman::p_load(
    # DB Packages
    "DBI",
    "odbc",

    # Tidy
    "tidyverse",
    "dbplyr",
    "writexl",

    # Mapping Tools
    "tmaptools"
)

# Connection Obj ----
con <- dbConnect(
    odbc(),
    Driver = "SQL Server",
    Server = "server_name",
    Database = "db_name",
    Trusted_Connection = "TRUE"
)

# Tables ----
pav <- ...

pdv <- ...

# Query ----
geo_add <- ...

a <- pdv ...

add_geo <- a %>%...

# Make df ----
df <- add_geo ...

# Geocode File ####
# Initialize the data frame
geocoded <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

# First Loop ----
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress)) {
    print(paste("Working on geocoding: ", origAddress$FullAddress[i]))
    … code
}

# Get Non Found Records ----
# Get all records that were not found and geocode on city/town, state, zip
for(i in 1:nrow(origAddress)) {
    … code
}
# Clean up Records ----
geocoded <- origAddress %>%
    ...

# Insert into tbl ----
dbWriteTable(
    con
    , Id(
        schema = "smsdss"
        , table = "c_geocoded_address"
    )
    , geocoded
    , append = T
)

# Delete Dupes ----
dbGetQuery(
  conn = con
  , paste0(
    "
    DELETE X ...
    "
  )
)

# DB Disconnect ----
dbDisconnect(conn = con)

# Save missing ---- this is what fails
origAddress %>%
  filter(is.na(lat)) %>%
  select(Encounter, FullAddress, ZipCode, PartialAddress) %>%
  write_xlsx(
    path = "S:\\path_to_file\\daily_geocode_file.xlsx"
    , col_names = T
    )

# Clean env ----
rm(list = ls())
```

Any ideas? Maybe a permissions issue?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue: when I was running scripts in R studio everything worked fine. But when I used a task scheduler (Windows not taskscheduleR package) I was getting an error:

ifelse(append, "a", "w"), encoding = fileEncoding) : cannot open the connection

It worked for me when in the path you put backslash and put a normal slash before every space in path e.g.:

G:/Desktop\ Working\ Files/FridayFile.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help!

Writing a file via Windows Task Scheduler failed, because of a problem in the path. I couldn't find the right answer all morning. Finally I found the right answer to my problem. So I kind of repost the right answer (and I am not allowed to like it yet). Maybe it will be found faster.

In the R script I put a backslash before every space in the file path (like "test files" in example below). This solved the problem.

Try it yourself, R-script:

```
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb, "MTcars")
writeData(wb, sheet = 1, mtcars)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = "G:/RStudio/test\ files/result/MTcars.xlsx", overwrite = TRUE)
```

Note 1: If you want to add a picture you also need backslashes in the file path.

```
img <- "G:/Rstudio\test\ files/My\ company\ logo_small.png"
insertImage(wb, sheet = 1, file = img, startRow = 5, startCol = 11, width = 4, height = 1)
```

Note 2: When you use source (to create your dataframe), you don't need backslashes in the file path.

Note 3: I still had a problem caused by some advanced functions I loaded (I created a work around by checking if variable "mail" exists). Please don't give up if the solution above still doesn't work!